# Calculating general term formula of $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What's the general term formula of $a_n$, where

\begin{cases}
a_n = (n-1)(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})\\
a_1 = 0\\
a_2 = 1
\end{cases}

Comment: Hint: Let $b_n=a_n-na_{n-1}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$a_{n}-na_{n-1}=-(a_{n-1}-(n-1)a_{n-2})$$
so we have
$$a_{n}-na_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}$$
Let $\dfrac{a_{n}}{n!}=b_{n}$

Comment: I know! $a_n=n!(1-\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{x-1}}{x!})$